# Angular '#' turning into '%23' in email links

Tags: angularjs, parameters

I have an Angular site and I have a link to it, http://localhost:8000/#/#Lima,LMA that I want to send in an email to a colleague. However when they click the link in the email it is returned as http://localhost:8000/#/%23Lima,LMA and the site doesn't work.

If they copy the link from the email and paste it into the browser it remains http://localhost:8000/#/#Lima,LMA and the site works as expected.

I think this is happening because you can have only one unescaped # in an URL and I have two #'s.

Is there a workaround so I can still use the hash parameter and have the ability to send this link in an email?

Comment: Why do you have two?

Comment: you can't have `#` in the link anyways.they're **NOT** sent to the server when a link is clicked on.

Comment: I wanted to pass Lima,LMA as parameters and then parse them with $location.hash()

Comment: You can't have two hashes in the same URL.  Use `?` and `$location.search()` instead.

Comment: I was under the impression I could use two hashes in the same URL in the angular docs they give the example url of http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo#hashValue

Comment: I ended up using the `?` and `$location.search()` instead but am still confused why angular uses a url with two hashes in there example url if you cant have two hashes